# How to optimize this PHP code that includes SPLIT, ARRAY_WALK and JOIN?

Tags: php

My database contains records that have:

1) First line delimited with double \n\n and the rest delimited with \n:

```
Introduction 

Line 1
Line 2
```

2) Everything delimited with \n:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

3) Nothing delimited:

```
Introduction
```

My goal is to add ">>" before each line that's delimited with a single \n. The spaghetti dinner that I cooked (and it works) looks as follows:

```
list($intro, $details) = split("\n\n", $dbInput);
if ($details) {
    $temp = split("\n", $details);
    array_walk($temp, create_function('&$v,$k', '$v = ">> $v";'));
    $dbOutput = "$intro \n\n ".join("\n", $temp);
} else {
    $temp = split("\n", $intro);
    if (count($temp) > 1) {
        array_walk($temp, create_function('&$v,$k', '$v = ">> $v";'));
        $dbOutput = join("\n", $temp);
    } else $dbOutput = $temp[0];
}
```

An example of what I want to achieve:

```
Introduction

>> Line 1
>> Line 2
>> Line 3
```

or

```
>> Line 1
>> Line 2
>> Line 3
```

or

```
Introduction
```

QUESTIONS: How would I optimize this code to combine array_walk with split and join in the same statement somehow along the following lines:

```
$a = join("\n" , array_walk(split("\n", $a), create_function(('&$v,$k', '$v = ">> $v";')) ) );
```

Comment: Please add an example of how you would like your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal method would be to use `preg_prelace` to replace lines terminating in `\n` (and not `\n\n` with `>>` at the front.

My guess is you don't want the

```
Introduction
```

To have the `>>` in front?

In that case:

```
$pattern = '/([^\n]+)(?=\n(?!\n))|(?<=(?<!\n)\n)([^\n]+)/';
$replacement = '>>$1$2';
$subject = 'Introduction 

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3';

echo preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject);

/* echoes:
Introduction

>>Line 1
>>Line 2
>>Line 3
*/
```

Explanation of regex:

```
([^\n]+)(?=\n(?!\n))   # match a line followed by \n but not a \n\n
|                      # OR
(?<=(?<!\n)\n)([^\n]+) # match a line preceded by \n but not a \n\n
```

The first bit captures `Line1` and `Line2`, but not `Line3`, as this is terminated by end-of-string and not a `\n`. The second bit of regex captures `Line3`.

They also both exclude a single-line string like `Introduction`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. How would I add "!" to the Introduction line in the same query, or should I run another regex (I can come up with the syntax based on your example).

Comment: You'd run another regex. Something like replacing `/([^\n]+\n\n)/` with `!$1`.